# How can I make sure the content stays intact when I close and reopen the info window

Tags: html, jquery-gmap3

I am outputting the Google Map info window with id created in javascript, but when I close and reopen the info window, there is 
Disappear content in the info window.
Tap the marker to display an info window with no contents
Press the 'report' button to display the contents in the information window.
How can I make sure the content stays intact when I close and reopen the info window?

If   continues to run in the background, I think it will be resolved.

javascript code

```
function display_c(start){
        window.start = parseFloat(start);
        var end = 172800; // change this to stop the counter at a higher value
        var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        if(window.start >= end ){
            alert("Time Over ");
        } else {
            mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
        }
    }

    function display_ct() {
        // Calculate the number of days left
        var days=Math.floor(window.start / 86400);
        // After deducting the days calculate the number of hours left
        var hours = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ))/3600)
        // After days and hours , how many minutes are left
        var minutes = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ))/60)
        // Finally how many seconds left after removing days, hours and minutes.
        var seconds = Math.floor((window.start - (days * 86400 ) - (hours *3600 ) - (minutes*60)))

        var x = days + "day " + hours + "hour " + minutes + "minute " + seconds + "second";


        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
        window.start= window.start+ 1;

        tt=display_c(window.start);
    }


// Handle Cordova Device Ready Event
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {

    var markerCount=0;

    var mapOpts = {
        center: [37, 127],
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl:false,
        fullscreenControl:false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    function genId() {
        return '' + (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    function placeMarker(map, event) {
            $(this).gmap3({
                marker: {
                    latLng: event.latLng,
                    id:markerCount,
                    data:'<span id="ct"></span>',
                    options: {
                        draggable: true,
                        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png"
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function(marker, event, context){
                            console.log(marker);
                            var lat=marker.position.lat();
                            var lng=marker.position.lng();

                            var map = $(this).gmap3("get");

                            map.panTo(marker.position);

                            var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                                infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
                            if (infowindow){
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                infowindow.setContent(context.data);
                            } else {
                                $(this).gmap3({
                                    infowindow:{
                                        anchor:marker,
                                        options:{content: context.data}
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        },

                    }

                }
            });
        }


    $('.map-object').gmap3({
        map: {
            options: mapOpts,
            events: {
                click: placeMarker
            }
        }
    });

    $('#report').click(function(){
        window.start= window.start+ 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it

```
var timer = document.getElementsByClassName('ct');
for (var i = 0; i < timer.length ; i++){
    timer[i].innerHTML = x;
}
```